# Trying to use 'ugly urls' with mediawiki install

Tags: url-rewriting, mediawiki

So, I'm in a bit of a weird place. I have a local mediawiki install I've been trying to get running.

Installation went off without a hitch, however I cannot access the wiki when it uses the more normal URL ("localhost/mywiki/index.php/Main_Page"). However, it works fine when using the so-called 'ugly' URL ("localhost/mywiki/index.php?title=Main_Page").

So, with that in mind, I've been trying to set up my mediawiki (version 1.29) to use the "ugly URL"s via the "$wgArticlePath" setting. I've tried a number of different setups, including the following:

- $wgArticlePath = "$wgScript?title=$1";
- $wgArticlePath = "$wgScriptPath?title=$1";
- $wgArticlePath = "$wgScriptPath/wgScript?title=$1";

But none of them will actually return what I need them to. If anyone has more experience with mediawiki, I'd appreciate the assist.

Comment: Have you tried to enable the `rewrite` module of Apache?

Answer (score 2):

Try to set [`$wgUsePathInfo`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgUsePathInfo) to `false`. Or set up a nice URL with the [short URL builder](https://shorturls.redwerks.org/).

Comment: Setting the $wgUsePathInfo to false absolutely fixed the issue, you thank you, Tgr! The short url builder, sadly, doesn't seem to want to work; I suspect because the wiki is a purely local affair, with no connection to the greater online network.Either way, cheers!